# Play audio over an active phone call, so other end can hear it

Tags: android

A and B are talking on the phone. During the call, A presses a button that pulls audio from a resource and plays it over the phone call to B.

Is this possible using the Android framework? The goal is for the person on the other end of the call to hear the audio.

If it's not possible, is it a hardware limitation or a limit of the Android framework?

Comment: Android is implemented on multiple hardware platforms, so it's impossible to state definitively that it's a hardware limitation.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that you cannot achieve that, according to the documentation [**HERE**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) :

> Note: You can play back the audio data only to the standard output device.
>   Currently, that is the mobile device speaker or a Bluetooth headset.
>   You cannot play sound files in the conversation audio during a call.

Comment: Ok, So can we use another Android device as a Bluetooth headset?

Answer (score 4):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html, there are a number of channels though which audio can be played:

- `STREAM_ALARM` The audio stream for alarms
- `STREAM_DTMF` The audio stream for DTMF Tones
- `STREAM_MUSIC` The audio stream for music playback
- `STREAM_NOTIFICATION` The audio stream for notifications
- `STREAM_RING` The audio stream for the phone ring
- `STREAM_SYSTEM` The audio stream for system sounds
- `STREAM_VOICE_CALL` The audio stream for phone calls

These are what the android framework allows for. It would seem to me that two are of potential interest to you: `STREAM_DTMF` or, more likely, `STREAM_VOICE_CALL`. I haven't experimented personally, but if I was trying to do this, I would start by trying those two.